# image processing close edge matlab

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I have  [the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhjzb.jpg)

What I need to do is connect the edges in MATLAB that are obviously of the same object in order to use regionprops later. By 'obviously' I mean the edges of the inside object and those of the outside one. What I thought is that I somehow must keep the pixels of each edge in a struct and then for each edge find the one that is closer to it and then apply some fitting(polynomial, bspline etc). The problem is that I have to make it for thousands of such images so I need a robust algorithm and I cannot do it by hand for all of them. Is there a way for somebody to help me? The image of which the previous image is obtained is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lrI6.png). Ideally I have to catch the two interfaces shown there.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: May you give also an example of the expected result referred to the given input image so that it will be easier to understand what is 'obviously' meaning?

Comment: @Diego Mazzaro I have just uploaded the original image. Hope this helps.